# Bootstrap buttons and columns expanding the entire width of a div tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a bootstrap calculator using the grind system provided by Bootstrap. I have two rows using the class col-md-4 with each row comprising of 4 buttons. I would expect to see the buttons expand the entire width of the div tag. When I put a background color to the div tag the color fills the entire div tag, as I would except. I created a codepen to illustrate my problem.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="cal-body">
<div class="header">
</div>  
<div class="lcd"> 
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <button>7</button>
   <button>8</button>
   <button>9</button>
   <button>%</button>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
  <div  class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
   <button>4</button>
   <button>5</button>
   <button>6</button>
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
  </div>   
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In other words, I would like my buttons to take of the full length of the column row. As of now, it only takes 1/4 of the column space. I am trying to replicate the look of a calculator.
My code pen:http://codepen.io/louis345/pen/KNoypX

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please more detail your idea, it's difficulty understand

Comment: `div class="4"` is unknown right?

Comment: let me rewrite it.

Comment: every row should be 12 columns. you just use one 4 column in every row

Comment: or else can you just post a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve a similar look to a calculator and trying to have the buttons expand the entire width of the column. My codepen should me adequate as you can see that the buttons are not taking of the entire length of the row.

Comment: then you need to use `col-md-12`

Comment: I I have a row and the inner div tag now is the class "col-md-12" with 4 buttons(button)inside the div tag. I still have about 50% percent of empty space left.

Comment: @claudios I got it work by using the col-md-12 and expanding the button width by 22%.

Comment: Great! glad to help.

Comment: @SaoriImai doing that `width: 22%` you are not correctly using bootstrap there, you should set every button as `col-md-X` so you get the desired width, and use `text-center`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `col-md-4` to `col-md-12` if you want to span the whole row. 
You can also add class `text-center` into your columns to make buttons centered position.

Sample:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">

</div
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://codepen.io/dgarcias/pen/WoPqvE) to see if that's what you are looking for

The idea is to wrap each button on a different column

```
<div class="col col-sm-3">
  <button>7</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@claudios your answer is right [ use class (**text-center**) ] and I am just implement in this snippet.

```css
.line{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 2px #ccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12 text-center line">
       <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
       <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each row has 12 columns, you're setting a div to use 4 columns and it will make the div to use 1/3 of the size.
Also, col-md must be used to sizes >= 768px. You should use col-xs because you're limiting the size of cal-body.

I made it, based on your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQMeXQ

Take a look here, 2 rows, each one has 4 divs, each using 3 columns.

```
<style>
  .button-group {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .button-line {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .button-col {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .button-col button{
   width: 100%;
 }
</style>

<div class="button-group">
  <div class="row button-line">
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>7</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>8</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>9</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>%</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row button-line">
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 button-col">
      <button>x</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```